# Move group header data into rows and remove header rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with product data like:

```
Item,Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4,Val5  
SomeProductName1,,,,,  
SomeProductDetails1,,,,,  
ProductGroupHeader1,,,,,  
ProductInfo1,39,8,6,94,112  
ProductInfo2,32,7,4,94,112  
ProductGroupHeader2,,,,,  
ProductInfo3,39,8,6,94,112  
ProductInfo4,32,7,4,94,112  
SomeProductName2,,,,,  
SomeProductDetails2,,,,,    
ProductGroupHeader21,,,,,  
ProductInfo21,39,8,6,94,112  
ProductInfo22,32,7,4,94,112  
ProductGroupHeader2,,,,,  
ProductInfo23,39,8,6,94,112  
ProductInfo24,32,7,4,94,112
```

I need it as:

```
Item,Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4,Val5  
SomeProductName1, SomeProductDetails1, ProductGroupHeader1,,,,,  
SomeProductName1, SomeProductDetails1, ProductInfo1,39,8,6,94,112  
SomeProductName1, SomeProductDetails1, ProductInfo2,32,7,4,94,112  
SomeProductName1, SomeProductDetails1, ProductGroupHeader2,,,,,  
SomeProductName1, SomeProductDetails1, ProductInfo3,39,8,6,94,112  
SomeProductName1, SomeProductDetails1, ProductInfo4,32,7,4,94,112  
SomeProductName2, SomeProductDetails2, ProductGroupHeader21,,,,,  
SomeProductName2, SomeProductDetails2, ProductInfo21,39,8,6,94,112  
SomeProductName2, SomeProductDetails2, ProductInfo22,32,7,4,94,112  
SomeProductName2, SomeProductDetails2, ProductGroupHeader2,,,,,  
SomeProductName2, SomeProductDetails2, ProductInfo23,39,8,6,94,112  
SomeProductName2, SomeProductDetails2, ProductInfo24,32,7,4,94,112
```

In essence, I want to get the `SomeProductName` and `SomeProductDetails` from their respective rows, remove those rows and then add the values as 2 columns in the `ProductInfo` rows

The csv has several thousand rows and my initial thought would be to just loop through updating and deleting rows according.

I then intend to pivot the data based on the `ProductName` and possibly plus `ProductDetails`

I'm new to pandas and python and just wondered if there was an easier/more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit your expected output you can do it with mask where all values are nan with `filter` and `isna`. Assuming the structure is rigorous, you can find Name and Details rows using `shift`. Then `concat` the Name and Detail columns, created with `where` and `ffill`, to df and select only the rows you want.

```
#get the rows with nan in all values columns
m = df.filter(like='Val').isna().all(1)
# get the rows with ProductName, it is where 
# all val are nan and also where all val are nan two rows later (GroupHeader rows)
name = m&m.shift(-2)
# get the rows with ProductDetails, it is where 
# all val are nan the row before (ProductName rows) 
# and also all val are nan one row later (GroupHeader rows)
details = m & m.shift(-1) & m.shift(1)

# you can create the dataframe wth concat, 
# use where to and ffill to keep name and details on followinf rows
df_ = (pd.concat([df['Item'].where(name).ffill().rename('Item_name'), 
                  df['Item'].where(details).ffill().rename('Item_details'), 
                  df], 
                 axis=1)
          [~(name|details)] #remove rows with only name and details
      )
```

and you get

```
print (df_)
           Item_name         Item_product                  Item  Val1  Val2  \
2   SomeProductName1  SomeProductDetails1   ProductGroupHeader1   NaN   NaN   
3   SomeProductName1  SomeProductDetails1          ProductInfo1  39.0   8.0   
4   SomeProductName1  SomeProductDetails1          ProductInfo2  32.0   7.0   
5   SomeProductName1  SomeProductDetails1   ProductGroupHeader2   NaN   NaN   
6   SomeProductName1  SomeProductDetails1          ProductInfo3  39.0   8.0   
7   SomeProductName1  SomeProductDetails1          ProductInfo4  32.0   7.0   
10  SomeProductName2  SomeProductDetails2  ProductGroupHeader21   NaN   NaN   
11  SomeProductName2  SomeProductDetails2         ProductInfo21  39.0   8.0   
12  SomeProductName2  SomeProductDetails2         ProductInfo22  32.0   7.0   
13  SomeProductName2  SomeProductDetails2   ProductGroupHeader2   NaN   NaN   
14  SomeProductName2  SomeProductDetails2         ProductInfo23  39.0   8.0   
15  SomeProductName2  SomeProductDetails2         ProductInfo24  32.0   7.0   

    Val3  Val4   Val5  
2    NaN   NaN    NaN  
3    6.0  94.0  112.0  
4    4.0  94.0  112.0  
5    NaN   NaN    NaN  
6    6.0  94.0  112.0  
7    4.0  94.0  112.0  
10   NaN   NaN    NaN  
11   6.0  94.0  112.0  
12   4.0  94.0  112.0  
13   NaN   NaN    NaN  
14   6.0  94.0  112.0  
15   4.0  94.0  112.0
```

Edit, to add the groupheader as a column, you can create a similar mask and then use it the same way in the concat:

```
#rows where all values are nan but not next row
groupHeader = m&(~m).shift(-1)

df_ = (pd.concat([df['Item'].where(name).ffill().rename('Item_name'), 
                  df['Item'].where(details).ffill().rename('Item_details'), 
                  df['Item'].where(groupHeader).ffill().rename('Item_group'), #add this
                  df], 
                 axis=1)
          [~(name|details|groupHeader)] #remove also the rows with groupHeader only
      )
```

Comment: That's excellent, thanks. If I also wanted the ProductGroupHeaders as a column as per the other 2 how would I achieve that?